# If I use synthetic/food safe grease will my front end loader or backhoe have excessive wear?

Tags: lubrication, wear, grease, tractor

I have a small tractor with a frontend loader and backhoe that gets used near our house's well and natural creeks/drainage areas.  I wouldn't mind paying the premium for synthetic grease to try and reduce the ground pollution--but so far it sounds like moly grease is required for the attachments that see high pressure.

My understanding is that synthetic, generally speaking, requires less frequent application but costs several times more.  However it sounds like it doesn't provide the same wear resistance for loaders/hoes.

Is this correct?  If I were to solely use synthetic, even greasing as often as I do with moly, should I expect accelerated wear?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't understand your question, moly grease is synthetic, food safe grease is usually a natural product. What are you using, and what are you trying to compare it against?

Comment: I've been using lithium-based moly grease -- usually either a Shell Rotella or Kubota.  I was considering switching to something like the Kubota HP Synthetic Extreme Duty (#77700-06321) which is listed as food grade--the Kubota Moly doesn't mention being food safe, and its data sheet has a warning to keep away from food, drink, animal feed equipment: https://www.kubotausa.com/docs/default-source/safety-data-sheets/product-name/kubota-moly-lithium-grease-70000-10401-grease-100516.pdf?sfvrsn=95a2dd1b_4